# CVPixelBufferRef to NSImage

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nsimage

How can I convert a CVPixelBufferRef to an NSImage or CGImageRef? I need to be able to display the contents of the pixel buffer in a Core Animation Layer.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the buffer to an image, you need to first convert the buffer to an `CIImage`, which then can be converted to an `NSImage`.

```
let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer)

let context = CIContext(options: nil)
```

From here you can go to both `GCImage` and `NSImage`:

```
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer)
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer)

let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
```